# The difference_type of ostreambuf_iterator<char> is void?

Tags: c++, type-traits

Today I was replacing a low level C-stylish method which saves a buffer to a file. The whole thing looked like this:

```
bool Profile::save(const char* path)
{    
    FILE* pFile = fopen(path, "w");
    BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT((pFile)) {
        fclose(pFile);
        pFile=NULL;
    } BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_END

    if(pFile == 0)
    {
        LOG_ERROR("could not open profile");
        return false;
    }

    size_t nWriteSize = fwrite(DataBlock, 1, sizeof(DataBlock), pFile);
    if(nWriteSize != sizeof(DataBlock))
    {
        LOG_ERROR("Only " << nWriteSize << " of " << sizeof(DataBlock) << "bytes written");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

This method actually contained a bug where it would segvfault if it couldn't find the file to open (inside BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT we neglected to check if pFile!=NULL). So I thought I'd rewrite the whole thing in a more idiomatic C++ fashion. Here's what I came up with:

```
bool Profile::save(const char* path)
{    
    std::ofstream profile(path, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

    if(!profile)
    {
        LOG_ERROR("could not open " << path);
        return false;
     }

    const char* pBeginOfBlock = reinterpret_cast<char*>(DataBlock);
    const char* pEndOfBlock   = reinterpret_cast<char*>(DataBlock + sizeof(DataBlock));


    std::ostreambuf_iterator<char> begin_file = std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(profile);
    std::ostreambuf_iterator<char> end_file = std::copy(pBeginOfBlock,
                                                        pEndOfBlock,
                                                        begin_file);

    const unsigned int BytesWritten = std::distance(begin_file, end_file);
    if(BytesWritten != sizeof(DataBlock))
    {
        LOG_ERROR("Only " << BytesWritten << " of " << sizeof(DataBlock) << "bytes written");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

However, this doesn't compile. It gives me an error for the line where I try to get the distance of the ostreambuf_iterators:

> error: void value not ignored as it ought to be

Apparently the difference_type ostreambuf_iterator of is void. How can I check that all bytes have actually been written to file? Is the check even necessary or does std::copy give some sort of guarantee?

Comment: as for the how do you check for error, `std::copy` can throw or the ostreamiterator used inside can throw. So you need to wrap the call in a `try catch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ostreambuf_iterator` is an output iterator, `std::distance` requires input iterators.

The error is perhaps a little cryptic but this is due to `difference_type` being `typedef`ed to `void`, i.e. trying to measure the distance between two `ostreambuf_iterator`s simply makes no sense, they cannot even be compared against one another.

Comment: Weirdly enough, the `value_type` of output iterators also seems to be `void` -- at least for a `std::back_insert_iterator`.

Comment: @KerrekSB Presumably that is to make certain other operations fail, such as `algorithm`s that take a predicate.

Comment: @user657267: I just got bitten by that when trying something [unrelated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26503729/596781), but the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/OutputIterator) says that output iterators have no notion of a "value type", since they may accept arbitrary assignments. Learn something new every day :-S