# Better way to convert a vector of uint8 to an ascii hexadecimal string

Tags: c++, vector, std

I coded the following function to convert a `std::vector` of `uint8_t` to an ascii hexadecimal `string` *(gnu++98 standard).*

```
 ...
string uint8_vector_to_hex_string(const vector<uint8_t>& v) {
    stringstream ss;
    vector<uint8_t>::const_iterator it;

    for (it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++) {
        char hex_char[2];
        sprintf(hex_char, "%x", *it);
        ss << "\\x" << hex_char;
    }

    return ss.str();
}
 ...
```

It works fine. I was wondering if there is a better way to do this transformation, maybe using not both the `stringstream` object and the `sprintf` function. Any suggestion?

Comment: use profiler, find bottlenecks, make it work faster.

Comment: How to print capital letters (eg. 0x1B instead of 0x1b)?

Comment: @Anna Vopureta: Use %X instead of %x.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the stringstream directly to do hex formatting:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

...

string uint8_vector_to_hex_string(const vector<uint8_t>& v) {
    stringstream ss;
    ss << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
    vector<uint8_t>::const_iterator it;

    for (it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++) {
        ss << "\\x" << std::setw(2) << static_cast<unsigned>(*it);
    }

    return ss.str();
}
...
```

Comment: For those wondering, you need to have `#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>`

Answer (score 5):

(*Note*: The answer is for standard C++; minor modifications regarding range iteration may be needed to work in older dialects. I consider those immaterial to the core problem of algorithmic efficiency that's salient to the question.)

You can save yourself a ton of work by realizing that you basically know the answer in advance and don't need to do all this dynamic work.

```
std::string uint8_vector_to_hex_string(const vector<uint8_t>& v)
{
    std::string result;
    result.reserve(v.size() * 2);   // two digits per character

    static constexpr char hex[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    for (uint8_t c : v)
    {
        result.push_back(hex[c / 16]);
        result.push_back(hex[c % 16]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

---

In the spirit of "recognizing the algorithm", here's a separated algorithm for place-value formatting of numeric sequences. First the use case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// bring your own alphabet
constexpr char Alphabet[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

// input
std::vector<unsigned char> const v { 31, 214, 63, 9 };

// output (Note: *our* responsibility to make allocations efficient)
std::string out;
out.reserve(v.size() * 2);

// the algorithm
place_value_format<char,     // output type
                      2,     // fixed output width
                     16>(    // place-value number base
    v.begin(), v.end(),      // input range
    std::back_inserter(out), // output iterator
    Alphabet);               // digit representation
```

Now the algorithm:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template <typename Out, std::size_t NDigits, std::size_t Base,
          typename InItr, typename OutItr>
OutItr place_value_format(InItr first, InItr last, OutItr out, Out const * digits)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first)
    {
        Out unit[NDigits];

        auto val = *first;

        for (auto it = std::rbegin(unit); it != std::rend(unit); ++it)
        {
            *it = digits[val % Base];
            val /= Base;
        }

        out = std::copy(std::begin(unit), std::end(unit), out);
    }

    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using Boost in your project you can use [boost::hex](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/algorithm/doc/html/the_boost_algorithm_library/Misc/hex.html)

```
#include <boost/algorithm/hex.hpp>

std::string uint8_vector_to_hex_string(const std::vector<uint8_t> & v) {
    std::string result;
    result.reserve(v.size() * 2);
    boost::algorithm::hex(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(result));
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for something with no dependencies on other classes:

```cpp
std::string uint8_vector_to_hex_string(const std::vector<uint8_t>& v) {
    std::string result;
    result.resize(v.size() * 2);
    const char letters[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    char* current_hex_char = &result[0];
    for (uint8_t b : v) {
        *current_hex_char++ = letters[b >> 4];
        *current_hex_char++ = letters[b & 0xf];
    }
    return result;
}
```